# Solving a linear system of congruences

Tags: systems-of-equations, congruences

> Solve the following linear system of congruences
>   \begin{cases}
> 18x \equiv  15  &\pmod{21}\\
> 6x \equiv  7  &\pmod{11}\\
> 3x \equiv  6 &\pmod{8} 
> \end{cases}

My work: first step i simplify first equation dividing by 3.

\begin{cases}
6x \equiv  5  \pmod 7 \\
6x \equiv  7  \pmod{11} \\
3x \equiv  6 \pmod 8
\end{cases}

now, for convenience, the teacher advised us to get coefficient 1 to the first member then I multiply first equation by 6, second equation by 2 and third equation by $3$ :

\begin{cases}
36x \equiv  30  \pmod 7  \\
12x \equiv  14  \pmod{11} \\
9x \equiv  18 \pmod 8 
\end{cases}

now doing mod :

\begin{cases}
x \equiv  2  \pmod 7  \\
x \equiv  3  \pmod{11} \\
x \equiv  2 \pmod 8
\end{cases}

the solution of first equation is:

$$ 2+7*k $$

use this for resolve second equation :

$$ 2+7*k \equiv 3 \pmod{11} $$

$$7*k \equiv 1 \pmod{11}) $$

Now , I don't know if it's correct,but for resolve this equation I multiply by $8 
so that
$ 7*8=56; $   
$56 \bmod 11 =  1$

so I get :

$ 56k \equiv 8 \pmod{11} $
after mod : 
$ k \equiv 8 \pmod{11} $

$ k = 8 $

Now we found the "x" of first solution :

$ 2+7 * k$  now $k = 8 $

$ 2+7*8 = 58 ; $

I multiply the first and second mod equations : 
$ 7*11 = 77 $

we have that $ 58+77*t $

or in other words :  class of $58 \mod 77 $

Now repeat the same procedure for third equation :

$ 58+77*t \equiv 2 \pmod 8 $

$ 77*t \equiv -56 \pmod 8$

$ 5t \equiv 0 \pmod 8 $

$ t \equiv 0 \pmod 8$

Now, this zero has put bit of confusion in my head :

what is the result ?

in theory we have
$$ 58 +77 * 0$$ 
Is correct ??

then

the product of the modules is $ 7*11*8 = 616  $

the result is $ 58 + 616 * h  $
or 
class 58 mod 616

everything is correct ?
I have a little doubt, sorry

Comment: I have a problem with use congruence symbol's
a\equiv b\pmod n  not work ... sorry

Comment: I wonder how you managed to write nice and pretty the first part...and then the horror! Mistery...

Comment: @DonAntonio 
I don't see this comment constructive, help me and not just say horror ... :)
the special character \equiv for "congruences" not work .. Help

Comment: @Z1pp3d How could you forget dollar signs after some point when you used them in the beginning?

Comment: What is your doubt? I edited the statement of the problem. Please revise your work and improve your editing. BTW it should be $x \equiv  2 \pmod{8}$.

Comment: @RobertZ thaks, but it's the first time for me to posting. Thanks for editing. 
$ x \equiv 1 (mod 8)$ is an error of transcription ... Yes is $ 2 (mod 8)$ 
 
But final result is good ?  class of 58 mod 616 ?!

Comment: @Z1pp3d Would you mind to correct and revise your editing? It's very hard to read.

Comment: @RobertZ 
I've done my best for editing :D ,bring patience... there are the first posts
thanks a lot!
PS: 
I don't understand -1 reputation ... what?!

Comment: @Z1pp3d Why don't you change $x \equiv  1 \pmod{8}$ to $x \equiv  2 \pmod{8}$? As regards the editing you can do much better! Take a look here: https://math.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: @Z1pp3d That was my way to tell "make an effort with **all** the question and not only with the first part, otherwise I, and probably other as well, won't even try to read that." Apparently it worked...and thus it really was constructive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your result is right, but your method is far too complex.

The solutions of systems of congruences relies on  *Bézout's identity* and the explicit formula for the inverse isomorphism in the *Chinese remainder theorem*, namely

> Suppose the moduli $m$ and $n$ are coprime, and let $um+vn=1$ a Bézout's relation. Then the system 
>   $$\begin{cases}x\equiv\alpha\pmod m\\x\equiv\beta\mod n\end{cases}\enspace \text{ has for solution(s) }\enspace x\equiv\beta\, um+\alpha\, vn\pmod {mn}.$$

Now, you can begin solving congruences $(1)$ and $(3)$: since $8-7=1$, 
$$\begin{cases}x\equiv 2\pmod 7\\x\equiv 2\mod 8\end{cases}\iff x\equiv 2\pmod{56}.$$
So  we now have to solve a system of two congruences modulo $56$ and modulo $11$. As $56-5\times 11=1$, we have
$$\begin{cases}x\equiv 3\pmod{11}\\x\equiv 2\pmod{56}\end{cases}\iff x\equiv 3\times56-2\times 5\times 11= 58 \pmod{616}.$$

Comment: where 58 congruous 1 mod 8 in my solution ?

Comment: The result is correct. It should be $x \equiv  2 \pmod{8}$

Comment: @Z1pp3d: Your last (simplified) congruence is $x\equiv 1\pmod 8$.

Comment: @RobertZ: See the last simplified congruence in the O.P.

Comment: $9x \equiv  18 \pmod{8}$ is equivalent to  $x \equiv  2 \pmod{8}$!!

Comment: Yes, but is an error of transcription :) ... the final result is right ? 
The method for resolve is good ?

Comment: With this modification, your result is correct, but I think your method is recommendable: if one can avoid expliciting the details of congruences, one should do it: they were introduced by Gauß for that.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Bernard . I'm not a Mathematical or a profound connoisseur of congruences. I study computer-science at university and prof shoved us this method for resolve a linear system of congruences..